# How can the main window title in Squeak and Pharo be set?

Tags: window, title, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

How can the main window title in Squeak and Pharo be set?

In Pharo I thought it could be set in the System -> Settings Menu but couldn't find anything there.

Can it be set only in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in Squeak:

```
HostWindowProxy basicNew primitiveWindowTitle: 1 string: 'My Title' squeakToUtf8
```

In Etoys we have a convenience method for this:

```
DisplayScreen hostWindowTitle: 'My Title'
```

(because Etoys shows the current project name as window title)

Comment: It looks like the necessary HostWindowPlugin is not implemented for Linux but it works on Windows with both Pharo 1.4 and 2.0

Answer (score 2):

This works in Pharo 3.0 (tested on Windows and Mac):
DisplayScreen hostWindowTitle: 'My Title'

Comment: Windows 10 and Pharo 6.1 is working as advertised as well.